# Why does mariadb's ANALYZE say "USING INDEX" when my search has a leading wildcard?

Tags: mariadb

I have a mariadb table with an index on username.  When I ANALYZE a query against USERNAME using LIKE "%name%", it claims that it is "using index".  But why?  How can you use an index with a leading wildcard?

```
MariaDB [ejbca]> ANALYZE SELECT fingerprint FROM CertificateData WHERE username LIKE "%thename%";
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows    | r_rows     | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | CertificateData | index | NULL          | certificatedata_idx2 | 1003    | NULL | 1421198 | 1539326.00 |   100.00 |       0.00 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
```

This is an AWS mariadb instance, with version `10.6.16-MariaDB-log`.

The Certificates table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `CertificateData` (
  `fingerprint` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `base64Cert` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `cAFingerprint` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificateProfileId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `endEntityProfileId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crlPartitionIndex` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expireDate` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `issuerDN` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `notBefore` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revocationDate` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `revocationReason` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rowProtection` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowVersion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serialNumber` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subjectAltName` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `subjectDN` varchar(767) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `subjectKeyId` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountBindingId` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updateTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificateRequest` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `invalidityDate` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fingerprint`),
  UNIQUE KEY `certificatedata_idx12` (`serialNumber`,`issuerDN`),
  KEY `certificatedata_idx2` (`username`),
  KEY `certificatedata_idx4` (`subjectDN`),
  KEY `certificatedata_idx5` (`type`),
  KEY `certificatedata_idx6` (`issuerDN`,`status`),
  KEY `certificatedata_idx7` (`certificateProfileId`),
  KEY `certificatedata_idx11` (`subjectKeyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Just curious, which MariaDB version and what is the table structure `show create table CertificationData` (edited into the question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it is reading through all of the index instead of all of the main body of table to find matching rows.  If the index is smaller than the main table data, this can be faster, especially if the index contains both the filtering column(s) and selected column(s).

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/:

> Using index

> Only the index is used to retrieve the needed information from the table. There is no need to perform an extra seek to retrieve the actual record.

Comment: Not quite "reading through all of...".  As the quote from the manual says, "Using index" means:  "Only the index is used...".  Still, the leading wildcard will necessitate "all of the index".

Comment: @RickJames right, the "all of" is specific to this case; I believe the ref NULL tells you that (even if you couldn't see the query itself)

Comment: Is it accurate to say that it's a "full table scan" over the index?  The index keys contains enough info to perform the query, but it reads through every index entry rather than using the index to perform an ordered search.

Comment: several places it is called a "full index scan" to differentiate it from a full table scan.  for instance, https://www.percona.com/blog/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/